# How to click on href inside a table AppleScript

Tags: javascript, applescript

i need click on 'href' on AppleScript

```
<a href="mailto:mail@gmail.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:#eb8900" target="_blank">mail@gmail.com</a>
```

i tried with

```
do JavaScript "document.querySelector('a[href=mailto:]').click();" in document 1
```

but don't work...

The email is dynamic because that i cant put

```
do JavaScript "document.querySelector('a[href=mailto:mail@gmail.com]').click();" in document 1
```

thanks for you help...

Comment: Only classnames are prefixed with a dot (.) in selectors. Instead the selector should be `'a[href*="mailto"]' `. Also the element name is `<a>`. `href` is an attribute.

Comment: thanks for you reply, i tried do JavaScript "document.querySelector('a[href=mailto:]').click();" in document 1... with out dot and dont work... ineed click in the href...

Comment: It should be `a[href*="mailto"]`. Your code is missing the double quotes around mailto: and the asterisk before the =
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: thanks for you help, this works '''a[href*=mailto]'''  , great job !